# How to query Graphql in Gatsby using parameters/arguments?

Tags: jquery, json, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to pass an argument to the query reading my json file, I have read a lot of tutorials and docs but maybe I am missing something because it doesn't work.

Here is the code

```
query MyQuery {
  allInternacionalJson {
    edges {
      node {
        regiones(id: 1) {
          id
          region
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the results are the following

```
{
  "data": {
    "allInternacionalJson": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "regiones": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "region": "América del Norte"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "region": "América Latina y el Caribe"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "region": "Europa"
              },
              {
                "id": 4,
                "region": "Asia Pacífico"
              },
              {
                "id": 5,
                "region": "Medio Oriente y África"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I viewed online that the 'where' search is no longer available and that the filter on top only applies to filtering nodes.

With that id what I am trying to do is to get only the object that has that id.

Answer (score 0):

The filters must go in the top-level of the query, `allInternacionalJson` in your case:

```
query MyQuery {
  allInternacionalJson(filter: {regions: {id: {eq: "1"}}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        regiones {
          id
          region
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: you don't even need to query the `id` if you don't need it for other purposes,.you can filter without query the parameter.*

Basically, you have to deep in each nested object to find your parameter (`id`) and apply the filtering rule `eq` (equals).

You can play and filter by clicking in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground to generate your filtered query.

Take a look at [GraphQL reference by Gatsby (filter section)](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#filter).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer but this doesn't work. I tried that query and on the filter parameter it says that "id" is not defined by type internacionalJson

Comment: I don't know if the schemas are being generated, I assume that they create themselves based on json

Comment: If this `.json` comes from your own data you must infer that schema and create an `id` field. If it comes outsource (external API) usually has comes from a unique `id`. If not, you should filter your query with another unique value based on the solution.

Comment: Yes, it comes from my own data but I haven't been able to create that schema, please help me

Comment: Can't you create any other unique field and query/retrieve it?

Comment: I don't know how to create the schema and documentation is confusing